# Access Data Frame Columns in R mmap objects

Tags: r

I am trying to port some code to use the mmap package. I am having an issue with accessing data frame columns.

I would like to be able to access data columns with the `$` and `[[` operators. Here is the results I am getting.

```
> foo <- as.mmap(mtcars)
> foo[,'mpg'] # works
    mpg
1  21.0
2  21.0
3  22.8
4  21.4
5  18.7
 ...
> foo$mpg #does not work
NULL
> foo[['mpg']] #also does not work
NULL
> foo[]$mpg #works
...
> foo[][['mpg']] #also works
...
```

Is there any way to make the `$` and `[[` operators work on the memory mapped object, as they would on a regular data frame?

Edit:
Per Joshua's suggestion I added a function for `[[`

```
`[[.mmap` <- function(x,...) `[[`(x[],...)
```

And for `$` which does not seem particularly elegant, but seems to work.

```
> `$.mmap` <- function(x,...) {
  if (...%in%c("storage.mode","bytes","extractFUN","filedesc")){
    get(...,envir=x) 
  }else {
    eval(call('$',x[],substitute(...)))
  }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions don't work because they don't have a `mmap` method.

```
> grep("mmap",methods("["),value=TRUE)
[1] "[.mmap"
> grep("mmap",methods("[["),value=TRUE)
character(0)
> grep("mmap",methods("$"),value=TRUE)
character(0)
```

Therefore, they dispatch to the default methods, which have no idea how to handle a `mmap`  object.  You would need to write `mmap` methods for `[[` and `$`.

Comment: Right @Joshua,  I'll think about adding these as methods - but they may conflict with the design of the class itself - not technically, but more philosophically, if that makes sense.  For now you can add your own methods to do what you want.

Comment: However, the [.mmap is not visible to the default namespace, so some other method must be dispatched for `[`. No?

Comment: @aaronjg: Methods do not have to be exported to be registered.  See `?S3Methods` (specifically the last paragraph of the Details section).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, That makes sense. I was able to get the `[[` function to work, but not the `$` function. I edited the original post with details.